# What does the &= operator do in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, boolean

What does the &= operator do in C#?

*For example:*

```
bool approved;
// Approved is a property of cra, also bool
approved &= cra.Approved;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **[See here for the MSDN documentation on the `&=` operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02(v=vs.80).aspx)**

Comment: @Robert: This question was too localized? Are you kidding?

Comment: @Jonathan: That's the close reason I use for ["General Reference"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) questions.  The comment is no longer here, but even the OP indicated that he was just asking the question as a test, and left a moderator flag indicating that he wanted the question to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a logical AND.

From MSDN ([& Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)):

> For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands;

In your code this is the same as:

```
approved = approved & cra.Approved;
```

Comment: I think you got the wrong operator.

Comment: @Robert - I most certainly didn't. The question was edited, and the original was asking about `&...`, not `&=`.

Comment: Ah, well then we both got duped, as well as the other people who posted answers (since they answered the edited question).

Comment: @Robert - Look at his comment history. It is now deleted, but he was commenting that this was a "test question".

Comment: All in all, a big waste of time for everyone.

Comment: @Robert - He probably only accepted my answer as he and I are both Israeli...

Answer (score 7):

It means it's a *compound assignment operator*. Just like:

```
i += 1;
```

is like

```
i = i + 1;
```

So

```
approved &= cra.Approved;
```

is like

```
approved = approved & cra.Approved;
```

where `&` is the logical AND operator in this case (because we're dealing with `bool` values; for integers it would be the bitwise AND operator).

See section 7.17.2 of the C# 4 spec for more details of the *exact* nature of compound assignment operators.

Comment: A new Jon Skeet fact:he can answer test/unreal questions.

Answer (score 2):

For the bool type, it is the logical-and assignment operator. For integral types, it is the bitwise-and assignment operator.

It is effectively the same as:

```
approved = approved & cra.Approved;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [AND assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It is basically doing:

```
approved = approved & cra.Approved;
```

Which will set approved to true if it was true previously AND cra.Approved is true.

Answer (score 1):

`a &= b` is equal to `a = (a & b)`.

The `&` operator performs a bitwise AND. This bitwise AND operation involves setting only those bits in the result that were originally set in both `a` and `b`.